# Ansible - looping over dynamically generated list items

Tags: list, loops, variables, ansible

Initial question regarding filtering out JSON was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505754/ansible-json-filtering). For visibility, the JSON, generated by registering the "list" output of the ec2_vol module, is (stdout):

```
{
"msg": {
    "failed": false,
    "changed": false,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "status": "in-use",
            "zone": "us-east-1a",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "voltag:/"
            },
            "encrypted": false,
            "iops": 120,
            "create_time": "2018-04-11T20:47:49.948Z",
            "snapshot_id": "snap-id",
            "attachment_set": {
                "device": "/dev/sda1",
                "instance_id": "iid",
                "deleteOnTermination": "true",
                "status": "attached",
                "attach_time": "2018-04-11T20:47:50.000Z"
            },
            "type": "gp2",
            "id": "volid",
            "size": 40
        },
        {
            "status": "in-use",
            "zone": "us-east-1a",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "voltag:/pgdata"
            },
            "encrypted": false,
            "iops": 120,
            "create_time": "2018-05-07T18:32:52.810Z",
            "snapshot_id": "",
            "attachment_set": {
                "device": "/dev/sdb",
                "instance_id": "iid",
                "deleteOnTermination": "false",
                "status": "attached",
                "attach_time": "2018-05-07T18:33:39.000Z"
            },
            "type": "gp2",
            "id": "volid",
            "size": 40
        }
    ]
},
"changed": false,
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

As was suggested in my previous post's "answer," adding a list element (e.g. `"{{ stdout.volumes[0].attachment_set.device }}"` ) did work, but I still need to loop through all list elements. I was able to get the indicies of the list above (which will range anywhere from 1 - 6, but in this case only has 2), by using the following code:

```
    - name: Get device indices
      set_fact:
        device_index: "{{ item }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{stdout.volumes | length -1}}
```

My problem now is that since I'm dynamically generating all of this data (the JSON & the indices), I don't know how to combine them into the next code block, which is:

```
    - name: Delete any existing snapshot
      ec2_snapshot:
        region: us-east-1
        aws_access_key: "{{ access }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ secret }}"
        instance_id: "{{ ec2_id }}"
        device_name: "{{ stdout.volumes[{{ item }}].attachment_set.device }}"
      with_items: "{{ device_index }}"
      tags: delete_existing
```

As you can see, I'm basically trying to combine the output of 2 "register" tasks (one register, one set_fact), and the code above doesn't work, because, "moustaches don't stack." I've also tried the following combination:

```
    - name: Get device indices
      set_fact:
        devices: stdout.volumes[{{ item }}].attachment_set.device
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{stdout.volumes | length -1}}

    - name: Delete any existing snapshot
      ec2_snapshot:
        region: us-east-1
        aws_access_key: "{{ access }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ secret }}"
        instance_id: "{{ ec2_id }}"
        device_name: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ devices }}"
      tags: delete_existing
```

But the above code results in `instance_vols.volumes[0].attachment_set.device` (and so forth) being input directly into the task as a string, and the variable doesn't get interpreted.

Comment: The way you create `device_index` is also flawed. Firstly - you overwrite the values and get a single number in result, not a list. Secondly, the number is a string, so you need to cast to integer `"{{ stdout.volumes[item|int].attachment_set.device }}"`. Fix it.

Comment: Changing the returned string to an int worked, thanks!